# How to configure AdBlock in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, adblock

I have Adblock and Adblock Plus extensions in Chrome browser.  I spend a lot of time doing intentional shopping and get blocked from things I don't want to be blocked from.  For example if I search google for a "hotspot", I want to research various devices available.  But when I click on one (sponsored link at the top of the search results), I get an error page that says

```
This site can’t provide a secure connection

ad.doubleclick.net sent an invalid response.
Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

I don't mind these "ads".  They are useful.  Is there a way to configure AdBlocker to allow them?

Comment: Does it work when the extensions are disabled? Because usually ad blockers don't interfere with SSL connections so I'd say it's more likely that this is caused by something else. Maybe best to try out the steps outlined at https://usefulpcguide.com/16820/fix-err_ssl_protocol_error-google-chrome/

Comment: determined it's my IT department

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My IT department admitted this is a filtering policy.  Quite unfortunate since looking at ads for new technology IS A HUGE PART OF MY JOB